# Can't free up purgeable space in macOS 11.3

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, disk-space

I've ran into this problem where my external Thunderbolt volume, which is formatted with encrypted APFS is not letting me free up any space, regardless of what I do.

When I first noticed, I manually went in and moved about 100GB from the drive in question to another location in order to free up space. However, when I went to save new stuff to the volume, it once again complained it was out of space.

This is what's being reported in DaisyDisk:

[image: DaisyDisk]

This is what `df` reports:

```
Filesystem       Size   Used  Avail Capacity iused       ifree %iused  Mounted on  
/dev/disk3s1    1.8Ti  1.8Ti   39Mi   100% 2603571 19530493869    0%   /Volumes/2bigRAID
```

If I run `du` on the disk, it reports a total of `880G` (the disk is 2TB).

This is the output of: `diskutil list external`:

```
/dev/disk1 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *2.0 TB     disk1
   1:                        EFI ⁨EFI⁩                     209.7 MB   disk1s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS ⁨Container disk3⁩         2.0 TB     disk1s2

/dev/disk3 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +2.0 TB     disk3
                                 Physical Store disk1s2
   1:                APFS Volume ⁨2bigRAID⁩                2.0 TB     disk3s1
```

This is the output of: `diskutil ap list disk3`:

```
+-- Container disk3 XXXXXXXX-XXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXX
    ====================================================
    APFS Container Reference:     disk3
    Size (Capacity Ceiling):      2000189177856 B (2.0 TB)
    Capacity In Use By Volumes:   2000149602304 B (2.0 TB) (100.0% used)
    Capacity Not Allocated:       39575552 B (39.6 MB) (0.0% free)
    |
    +-< Physical Store disk1s2 XXXXXXXX-XXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXX
    |   -----------------------------------------------------------
    |   APFS Physical Store Disk:   disk1s2
    |   Size:                       2000189177856 B (2.0 TB)
    |
    +-> Volume disk3s1 XXXXXXXX-XXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXX
        ---------------------------------------------------
        APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk3s1 (No specific role)
        Name:                      2bigRAID (Case-insensitive)
        Mount Point:               /Volumes/2bigRAID
        Capacity Consumed:         1999849660416 B (2.0 TB)
        Sealed:                    No
        FileVault:                 Yes (Unlocked)
```

Output of `diskutil info disk3s1`:

```
   Device Identifier:         disk3s1
   Device Node:               /dev/disk3s1
   Whole:                     No
   Part of Whole:             disk3

   Volume Name:               2bigRAID
   Mounted:                   Yes
   Mount Point:               /Volumes/2bigRAID

   Partition Type:            XXXXXXXX-XXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXX
   File System Personality:   APFS
   Type (Bundle):             apfs
   Name (User Visible):       APFS
   Owners:                    Disabled

   OS Can Be Installed:       Yes
   Media Type:                Generic
   Protocol:                  SATA
   SMART Status:              Verified
   Volume UUID:               XXXXXXXX-XXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXX
   Disk / Partition UUID:     XXXXXXXX-XXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXX

   Disk Size:                 2.0 TB (2000189177856 Bytes) (exactly 3906619488 512-Byte-Units)
   Device Block Size:         4096 Bytes

   Container Total Space:     2.0 TB (2000189177856 Bytes) (exactly 3906619488 512-Byte-Units)
   Container Free Space:      39.8 MB (39784448 Bytes) (exactly 77704 512-Byte-Units)
   Allocation Block Size:     4096 Bytes

   Media OS Use Only:         No
   Media Read-Only:           No
   Volume Read-Only:          No

   Device Location:           External
   Removable Media:           Fixed

   Solid State:               Yes
   Hardware AES Support:      No

   This disk is an APFS Volume.  APFS Information:
   APFS Container:            disk3
   APFS Physical Store:       disk1s2
   Fusion Drive:              No
   FileVault:                 Yes
   Sealed:                    No
   Locked:                    No
```

**I've tried the following:**

1. Used the CleanMyMac "Clean purgeable space" feature
2. Rebooted in recovery mode and ran First Aid on the disk
3. Made sure trashes are empty

All to no avail. I can't add any new files to this disk. I'm borderline considering making a copy of everything to another drive, re-formatting this one and then moving things back. But, it's an SSD and I'd rather avoid the unnecessary write cycles if there's something else I haven't considered.

Comment: Can you add the report of the terminal commands ``diskutil list external`` and ``diskutil ap list external``. Thanks

Comment: Hi 0x6A75616E - I had this problem too - and the solution is to write a large file to the disk (to use up all the space)... e.g. use dd (say writing in lots of 16mb)...  Then you delete the file, and that makes the purgeable space available - unfortunately it requires a write... the documentation says purgeable space comes back after a reboot (it didn't for me).

Comment: @MrR - I read about this approach too, however, when I try it it goes:  dd: ./largefile: No space left on device :(

Comment: @Jean_JD - Updated the question.. thanks

Comment: Hi @0x6A75616E - you will run out of space - that's the point of it - or are you saying it ran out too soon?  Also note mine wasn't encrypted APFS (although I would guess that's not significant to the problem).

Comment: @MrR The disk is supposed to have 1TB purgeable and yet that error message comes up almost right away.

Comment: @0x6A75616E - what's the command you used - is it possible you weren't referring to the right disk for the of=XX part of the dd?

Comment: Ok and one more please ;-)  ``diskutil info disk3s1``. . Have you activate the Raid Function on this Drive?

Comment: If I remember correctly, macOS tries to minimize the number of write cycles on an SSD to extend its lifespan, that's why the space is marked as purgeable and it's not physically deleted, hence the difference between DaisyDisk and `df`. The purgeable space will be freed "as necessary", for example when copying a file with the Finder, so you can create a large file on another drive with `dd if=/dev/random of=/Volumes/anotherdrive/largefile bs=10m count=20000` (this command creates a 200GB file) and then copy it to your `2bigRAID` disk using drag and drop. After doing so, check `df`'s output.

Comment: @MrR 100% sure I was on the right drive :)

Comment: @jaume tried this but Finder doesn't let me copy the file to the drive. Complains it's full.

Comment: @Jean_JD Updated the question. Yes.. it's a RAID drive. The physical container is a LaCIE thunderbolt, 2xdisk enclosure. thanks again!

Comment: You can list, sorted by space used, every element on this Volume (files or directories) with the 2 next commands : ``sudo du -sxg /Volumes/2bigRAID/* | grep -v permitted | sort -nr`` for "normal" elements and ``sudo du -sxg /Volumes/2bigRAID/.???* | grep -v permitted | sort -nr`` for hiden elements.

Comment: @0x6A75616E Could you try connecting the drive and emptying the trash?

Comment: I gave up.. I copied all the data off the drive, erased it and moved the data back in.. Hope it doesn't happen again :(.. Thanks for the suggestions, everyone!